# Continue training a FastText model

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

I have downloaded a `.bin` FastText model, and I use it with `gensim` as follows:

```
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format("cc.fr.300.bin")
```

I would like to continue the training of the model to adapt it to my domain. After checking [FastText's Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/423) and the [Gensim documentation](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/fasttext.py#L685) it seems like it is **not** currently feasible appart from using this person's proposed [modification](https://github.com/ericxsun/fastText) (not yet merged).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can continue training in some versions of Gensim's `fastText` (for example, v.3.7.*). Here is an example of "[Loading, inferring, continuing training](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model)"

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
model = load_facebook_model(datapath("crime-and-punishment.bin"))
sent = [['lord', 'of', 'the', 'rings'], ['lord', 'of', 'the', 'semi-groups']]
model.build_vocab(sent, update=True)
model.train(sentences=sent, total_examples = len(sent), epochs=5)
```

For some reason, the `gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model()` is missing on Windows, but exists on Mac's installation. Alternatively, one can use `gensim.models.FastText.load_fasttext_format()` to load a pre-trained model and continue training.

Here are various [pre-trained Wiki word models and vectors](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html) (or [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/docs/pretrained-vectors.md)).

[Another example](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/FastText_Tutorial.ipynb). "*Note: As in the case of Word2Vec, you can continue to train your model while using Gensim's native implementation of fastText.*"

Comment: In 2021 with gensim==3.6.0 `model.build_vocab()` throws `AttributeError: 'FastTextTrainables' object has no attribute 'syn1neg'`

Answer (score 0):

The pull request #1327 (https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/1327)

**Allows for:**

1. test after each epoch
2. checkpointing
3. training on large data which does not fit into memory (largest I tested was 1.6TB)
4. finetuning already trained models

The trained model is indistinguishable from a model that was created by an original tool and can be used for inference by the old code.

Answer (score -1):

The official FastText implementation currently doesn't support that, although there is an open ticket related to this issue which you can find [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/423).

Comment: Thanks, that's the one I referrenced in my question